# How to activate JSR-250 annotation into a Spring application that is not configured using the XML configuration file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I know that if I want use the **JSR-250** annotations inside a Spring application configured by XML configuration file I have to put this tag inside the XML configuration file:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

But what I need to do to activate the **JSR-250** annotations if I am using a Java configuration class or the annotations config instead the XML based configuration for my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent to `<context:annotation-config/>` is `@AnnotationDrivenConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@AnnotationDrivenConfig
public class Config {
    // may now use @Autowired to reference beans from other @Configuration classes, XML, etc
}
```